# Funcion lambda no reconoce una id dentro de una clase de usuarios

Tags: python, clase, lambda, funcion, fastapi

Este es mi codigo para la funcion lambda:

```
users = filter(lambda user: user.id = id, users_list)
```

Este es el codigo completo de la clase:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    lastname: str
    username: str
    email: str
    age: int

users_list = [User(id = 1, name = "Angel", lastname = "Henriquez", username = "legna", email = "legnanavi02@gmail.com", age = 20),
            User(id = 2, name = "Angel", lastname = "Henriquez", username = "legna", email = "legnanavi02@gmail.com", age = 20),
            User(id = 3, name = "Angel", lastname = "Henriquez", username = "legna", email = "legnanavi02@gmail.com", age = 20)]

@app.get("/users")
def users():
    return users_list

@app.get("/user/{id}")
def user(id: int):
    users = filter(lambda user: user.id = id, users_list)
    return list(users)
```

Comment: En la función `lambda` quieres hacer una comparación, no una asignación. Es decir, en vez de `user.id = id` sería `user.id == id`. `users = filter(lambda user: user.id == id, users_list)`

Comment: Si el `id` del usuario es único, quizás te interese más guardar los usuarios en un diccionario `{id : User}` en vez de en una lista. Así a la hora de buscar a un usuario, solo tendrías que hacer `diccionario.get(id)`

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionan en los comentarios anteriores para el correcto funcionamiento del filter se debe aplicar un operador de comparación en tu caso sería `==`

```
users = filter(lambda user: user.id == id, users_list)
```